# Why is my userid getting cut off?

Tags: php

In the array below, you'll see `userId = 16`. However, when I run a `foreach` loop, it returns `userId = 1`. Why is it returning `1` and not `16`?

```
Array
(
    [userId] => 16
    [positionTitle] => Array
        (
            [0] => j1
            [1] => j2
        )

    [company] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
        )

    [jobDescription] => Array
        (
            [0] => d1
            [1] => d2
        )

    [startDate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/01/2013
            [1] => 03/03/2013
        )

    [endDate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/02/2013
            [1] => 03/04/2013
        )

    [jobCity] => Array
        (
            [0] => city1
            [1] => city2
        )

    [jobState] => Array
        (
            [0] => state1
            [1] => state2
        )

)
```

Loop code:

```
foreach($updates as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " " . $value[0] . "<br/>";
}
```

Sample output:

```
userId 1
positionTitle j1
company c1
jobDescription d1
startDate 03/01/2013
endDate 03/02/2013
jobCity city1
jobState state1
```

Comment: your code does whatever you tell it to do. $value[0] = 1 and not 16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach($updates as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " " . $value[0] . "<br/>";
}
```

Youre outputting the 1st character (zeroth element ) of the string "16".

Change your code to this to get the desired effect:

```
foreach($updates as $key => $value){
    if(!is_array($value))
       echo $key . " " . $value . "<br/>";
    else
       echo $key . " " . $value[0] . "<br/>";
}
```